# Raspberry Pi 5 Reboot Instead of Shutdown

Tags: power-management, pi-5

With the Raspberry Pi 5, a power button has been added and the system can remain in power off mode. It's a nice feature, but it's been a problem lately. Yesterday I noticed that it could not access the device and when I went to check it, the power led was red and only turned back on when I pressed the power button. I didn't find anything extra in the log files, I think there was a small power surge and the device was turned off. I have a Raspberry Pi 4 and it would reboot even if you gave a shutdown command. Is there any way to achieve this on the Raspberry Pi 5 as well? So I want it to always reboot instead of shutdown.

I tried to change HandlePowerKey and using rc.local but they didn't work.

Comment: If the Pi5 is shutdown (however you do it; by command, button or power cut) it will boot when power is applied - just like any other Pi. If you shutdown a Pi4 you need to reapply power (unless you use the reboot button on pin 5).

Answer (score -1):

maybe just shut it down the normal way like with raspberry pi models 4 and 4b, or if you can't do that probably just work with your Pi4 from now on. Mine works, and  maybe it's better to use the old features than the new ones.

Comment: Raspberry Pi 4B can't handle the program that I run. RPi5's A76 processors are strong.

Comment: maybe not use your rpi 5 this time. I think if you stick with 4, you won't have much problems with this

Comment: or you could buy a new pi 4, just because i think some product copies are better than others